# PySide2 "QAnimationGroup::animationAt: index is out of bounds" warning

Tags: qt5, pyside2

I'm using PySide2, and the following example script generates the warning: `QAnimationGroup::animationAt: index is out of bounds`.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore

def add_animation(banner):
    anim1 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(None, "geometry")
    anim2 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(None, "geometry")
    banner.addAnimation(anim1)
    banner.addAnimation(anim2)

banner_animation = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(None)
add_animation(banner_animation)
# This is the line that generates the warning:
banner_animation.clear()
```

It seems that if I add more than one animation to the group and try to clear them, I get the warning. Adding a single animation does not result in a warning. I've tested with QT versions 5.12, 5.13, and 5.14.

Is this a bug or am I doing something strange here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I think it's probably a garbage collection issue. The `anim1` and `anim2` objects are being collected, as they cleared up when the method exits, but Qt is still holding a reference to them.
The following works for example:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore

def add_animation(banner):
    anim1 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(None, "geometry")
    anim2 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(None, "geometry")
    banner.addAnimation(anim1)
    banner.addAnimation(anim2)
    return anim1, anim2

banner_animation = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(None)
anim1, anim2 = add_animation(banner_animation)

banner_animation.clear()
```